# React Router Switch Redux Dispatch

Tags: react-redux, react-router

I have the below switch statement that routes the user to correct component based on the link they are on.

```
const Router = (props) => {
    switch(props.page) {
        case 'Equities' :
            this.props.pageName('Equities'); 
            this.props.pageURL('/Equities'); 
            return <Equities />;
        case 'Daily' : 
            return <Daily />;
        default :
            return ( <Redirect to="/Equities" /> )
    }
  }

const content = ({ match }) => {

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <Router page={match.params.type} />
        </div>
    );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    pageURL,
    pageName
   };

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(content);
```

On the 4th line above, I am trying to dispatch an action to Redux to update page name and URL in the redux store that the user is on. I get the below error:
[image]

How can I dispatch actions based on the page user is on so I update name and URL  to whichever page user is visiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone experiencing this problem, it seems to be caused by my error on adding redux to the page crashing with the compose module.

My component structure for the app is like this:
App -> Skeleton -> TopBar, Sidebar, Content

So inside Content component I have a switch that displays the correct content for user. I was trying to add this functionality to Content. Now I added to Skeleton, and it works fine and is much better because I don't need to add now 8 different statements inside switch saying if match this do this do that. Now all I have is `this.props.pageName(match.url); this.props.pageURL(match.params.type);` so I record in redux the user is on and that's all.